# Why can I make clothes in Blender that in MakeHuman don't fit in?

Tags: makehuman

[image]I make clothes in Blender and those clothes fit in the model but when I export them to MakeHuman don't fit in the model.
Why?

Comment: Is the scale of the clothing anything other than X:1,Y:1,Z:1?

Comment: The scale is X:1.000, Y:1.000, Z:1.000

Comment: Good, and how about your human model? The scales have to match, and if they don't you should Apply Scale.

Comment: When I work in Blender the clothing fits perfectly well I heard that I have to do the clothing a little bit bigger than the model so I did that. When I transfer the clothing to MakeHuman the same clothing has rare things.